# getting position of data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable, locate

My question is if the is a way to locate data in a JTable.

```
table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"Peter", new Integer(15)},
            {"Max", new Integer(12)},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Name", "Age"
        }
    )
```

Now I want the location of eg. 12 so that i can mark that when I klick on a button. And if also possible it will be nice if I can also search for a number or a name.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: *"Thank you in advance for your answers"* Thank you in advance for your question. Two notes. 1) You've outlined two desired goals. Each thread on SO should deal with **one** matter, not two. Start a separate thread for each. 2) A goal or requirement is not a question. Please don't forget to always ask a clear, specific question on this **question** & answer site. So.. what is your question?

Comment: You don't need to do `new Integer(...)` every time. The proper way is `Integer.valueOf(...)`, which uses caching for small numbers, but it will be triggered automatically by boxing if you just write an `int` literal because you have an array of objects. For example, replace `new Integer(12)` with just `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method to find the first row which contains the specified value in any column.

```
public static int firstRowContainsObject(JTable table, Object obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            if (Objects.equals(obj, table.getValueAt(i, j))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note: this method returns -1 if no such object found in the table.

Usage in your case:

```
firstRowContainsObject(table, 12); // returns 1 
firstRowContainsObject(table, "Peter"); // returns 0
firstRowContainsObject(table, "Mary"); // returns -1
```